# ¿Cómo poner etiquetas a un diagrama BoxPlot?

Tags: r

Estoy explorando la funcion `boxplot` en R, solo que quiero ponerle al gráfico las etiquetas de la media, q1, y q3 y no sé como se hace. ¿alguien sabe de algún paquete especifico con el que uno puede hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

En caso de tratarse de un `boxplot` básico de `R`, por ejemplo:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- cbind(Uni05 = (1:100)/21, Norm = rnorm(100),
             `5T` = rt(100, df = 5), Gam2 = rgamma(100, shape = 2))

boxplot(mat)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes aprovechar el objeto retornado por la función para obtener los valores de Q1, Q3 y la media, así:

```
bxp <- boxplot(mat)
bxp$stats

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.04761905 -2.2146999 -2.6698617 0.1184266
[2,] 1.21428571 -0.5103350 -0.7980927 0.8665581
[3,] 2.40476190  0.1139092 -0.1266147 1.5467609
[4,] 3.59523810  0.6933514  0.5191909 2.8100158
[5,] 4.76190476  2.4016178  2.2574027 4.7200702
```

Cada columna representa los `fivenum()` de cada grupo, por lo que para acceder a los valores deseados podemos hacer: `bxp$stats[c(2,3,4), <grupo>]`. Teniendo los datos, podemos usar `text()` para escribir la etiqueta con el valor. Para hacerlo con uno de los grupos en particular:

```
x <- 3                                                  # El grupo 3
text(x = x-.05,                                         # La posición x de la etiqueta
     labels = format(bxp$stats[c(2,3,4), x], digits=2), # Etiqueta: formateamos el número
     y = bxp$stats[c(2,3,4), x] + .15,                  # Posición y de la etiqueta
     cex = 0.6,                                         # Tamaño letra
     col = "blue",                                      # color de la letra
     font = 2                                           # negrita
     )
```

Esto mismo se puede aplicar a los cuatro grupos de la siguiente forma:

```
sapply(1:ncol(bxp$stats), function(x) {
               text(x = x-0.05, 
                    labels = format(bxp$stats[c(2,3,4),x], digits=2), 
                    y = bxp$stats[c(2,3,4),x]+.15, 
                    cex = 0.6, 
                    col = "blue", 
                    font=2)
               })
```

El resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]