# ¿Como poner etiquetas a un diagrama usando bloxplot?

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, plot, boxplot

Estoy explorando la función boxplot en R, solo que quiero ponerle al gráfico las etiquetas de la media, q1, y q3 y no sé como se hace. He revisado la solución de esta pregunta [¿Cómo poner etiquetas a un diagrama BoxPlot?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203481/c%C3%B3mo-poner-etiquetas-a-un-diagrama-boxplot), pero no he podido comprenderla usando mis datos, alguien me podria ayudar a resolverlo pls,
este es mi código:

```
attach(Datos_Estadisticas_Final_Copy)


boxplot(edad~genero,
        data=airquality,
        main="CUARTIL POR GENERO Y EDAD",
        xlab="Genero Sexual",
        ylab="Edad",
        col= c("red", "blue"),
        border="black",
        notch = T,
        yaxp = c(-10, 70, 20))
```

tengo dos columnas llamadas edad y género con nombre del Excel Datos_Estadisticas_Final_Copy

al realizar el plot del anterior código me muestra los siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma como lo estaba pensando

```
#genero x edad
boxplot(edad~genero,
        data=airquality,
        main="CUARTIL POR GENERO Y EDAD",
        xlab="Genero Sexual",
        ylab="Edad",
        col= c("red", "blue"),
        border="black",
        notch = T,
        yaxp = c(-10, 70, 20)) +
        text(x = x-.05,                                         
               labels = format(bxp$stats[c(2,3,4), x], digits=2), 
               y = bxp$stats[c(2,3,4), x] + .15,                
               cex = 0.6,                                       
               col = "blue",                                    
               font = 2                                           
          )
```

Comment: Particularmente ¿qué dificultado tienes con la pregunta que enlazas? te lo consulto por que tomé el código de esta y simplemente modifique los nombres de las variables por los tuyos, mas unos datos generados sintéticamente y consigo mostrar los 3 cuartiles.

Comment: En toda la sintaxis la verdad no entiendo varias cosas que aparecen en el codigo, por ejemplo en bxp$stats no sé que significa eso, te puse en el enunciado como lo estaba pensando, pero no he podio arreglarlo, si me puedes ayudar con la sintaxis y el codigo estaria agradecido :)

Comment: Te dejé una respuesta, espero la puedas ver, cualquier cosa sino date una vuelta por el [chat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a responder con tu ejemplo, pero ciertamente tu pregunta es duplicada de la que enlazas, simplemente lo que hice fue generar datos parecidos a los tuyos y cambiar los nombres de las variables en el código original

```
boxplot(edad~genero,
        data=Datos_Estadisticas_Final_Copy,
        main="CUARTIL POR GENERO Y EDAD",
        xlab="Genero Sexual",
        ylab="Edad",
        col= c("red", "blue"),
        border="black",
        notch = T,
        yaxp = c(-10, 70, 20)) -> bxp

stats <- bxp$stats[c(2,3,4),] # Dejamos Solo Q1, Q2, Q3

sapply(1:ncol(stats), function(x) {
  text(x = x, 
       labels = format(stats[,x], digits=2), 
       y = stats[,x]+2, 
       cex = 1.2, 
       col = "black", 
       font=2)
})
```

El gráfico de entrada lo asignamos a una variable `bxp` que entre sus atributos tiene los cuartiles de cada grupo `bxp$stats`, lo que hacemos luego es "dibujar" estos valores mediante la función `text()`. El resultado final sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ah vale ya revise mis errores, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)